# TFS2010: Publish nUnit test results

Tags: tfs, nunit

I have created custom build tasks in my project file to run my nUnit tests, convert them to the MSTest result format using an XSLT and call mstest /publish with all the appropriate parameters.  The build appears to be successful but I don't get any test results in the build report.

> PublishNUnitReportToTfs:   "C:\Program
>   Files (x86)\MSBuild..\Microsoft
>   Visual Studio
>   10.0\Common7\IDE\mstest.exe" /publish:"http://TFSBuildServer:8080/tfs/Acme
>   Development"
>   /publishbuild:"ci2.myApp.acme.com_20110526.15"
>   /publishresultsfile:"D:\Builds\2\myApp\ci2.myApp.acme.com\Sources\myApp.Core.nUnit.Tests..\nUnitResultsAsMsTestResults.xml"
>   /teamproject:"myApp"
>   /platform:"AnyCPU" /flavor:"Debug"
>   Microsoft (R) Test Execution Command
>   Line Tool Version 10.0.30319.1
>   Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation.
>   All rights reserved.
>            Waiting to publish...   The file
>   'D:\Builds\2\myApp\ci2.myApp.acme.com\Sources\nUnitResultsAsMsTestResults.xml'
>   was created in an earlier version of
>   Visual Studio. This file will be
>   converted, in memory only, to the
>   current format.   Publishing results
>   of test run tfssvc@TFSBuildServer
>   2011-05-26 15:47:54 to
>   http://TFSBuildServer:8080/tfs/Acme
>   Development...   ...........Publish
>   completed successfully.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found it!

After running the Build Quality Indicators report and playing with the report parameters I noticed there was an odd platform value, "AnyCPU" in addition to "Any CPU".  Then I checked the TFS warehouse database and found that my test results were making it to the database.  So I changed the platform flag on the mstest call to the static value "Any CPU" instead of using the $(Platform) build property and that fixed it.

Hope this helps someone else.

Answer (score 3):

I used [this website](http://www.heikura.info/publish-nunit-test-results-as-part-of-team-build-in-team-foundation-server-2010) to do exactly this. Hope this helps.

I'm assuming you've added nunit tests to your build by modifying the build template definition?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you specify the correct build number, platform and flavor in the MsTest command for the build you publish your tests against. Publishing test results in TFS 2010 does not check if build X with platform Y and flavor Z exists, it simply stores the test results against such configuration. When you query for the build, the build service will try to find the test results that match the its build configuration. So any mismatch between the real build configuration and the ones specified when publishing test results will result in the test results not being displayed on the build details view.

You asked a few days ago about custom configurations ("Dev" and "Test") instead of "Debug" and "Release", but I saw in this command you specified /flavor:"Debug" so I think that might be the culprit here.